# How to display the date_time in 2 lines in Python Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I received weather forecast data from Openweathermap using API and want to drawing it in graph using Matplotlib. The graph's title is the change of Temperature and Feels_like . On the x label I set time. But the 'time' data was written in **'2022-06-19 12:00:00'** form and because I plotted 3 hours' data per day in 5 days data so the graph was like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB4so.png)

Here is my code for matplotlib:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.title("Changes of Temperature and Feels_like")
plt.plot(time,temp,label="temperature")
plt.plot(time,feels_like,label="feels_like")
plt.xlabel("time(JST)")
plt.ylabel("temperature and feels_like(C)")
```

How to display the time in 2 lines like   **2022-06-19**

```
                               **12:00:00**
```

Comment: Please see: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/ticks_too_many.html

Comment: Jody Klymak  Thanks, it gave me idea to improve the problem of my graph!